How to display Field Quill in Django Views?
For my forum I am trying to use Quill Rich Text editor to format my Posts and comments.
class Topic(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
   description = QuillField(default="")

And managed to create some content <class 'django_quill.fields.FieldQuill'>
This is how it looks on admin form
I have tried display it in views using
<div class="">{{topic.description.html| safe}}</div>

This is how it looks in Views
I am using django-quill package enter link description here
I have included all the style and script tags as recommended and still the styles are not applying.
Any ideas how I can display the content as is.
I have tried:

Converting the delta type {"ops":[{"attributes":{"bold":true},"insert":"dqwdqwdqdqdq"},{"insert":"\n"}]} into html before saving the model. failed with error TypeError: 'FieldQuill' object is not subscriptable

Please recommend reliable packages to convert delta to html or display the content with all formatting.
TIA

Exactly what is not working? What is the expected outcome?

The format is not consistent with what was on the db. When tried to display in views using model.field.html|safe

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
